# Implementation of a logic circuit using NOR gates substituted for NAND ones

Tags: logic-gates, boolean-algebra

My goal is to implement logic function F = XY + ZW. In previous board, It was constructed by using three NAND gates as brought in below photo. Yet, by employing NOR gates, I have to make use of eight gates. Is there any design employing less NOR gates?

[image]

Comment: Not when you need to use them as inverters. If XYZW were inverted, then this nor option would make sense.

Comment: There are 4 input nor and nand gates, but that would make it too easy.

Answer (score 1):

If it were to be implemented using NOR gates only, eight is the minimum number while it is just three in case of NAND gates.

Comment: Can you explain to the OP *why* that is the case or how you proved it?

Comment: I worked it out and arrived at the similar number of NOR gates. It comes to 8.

Comment: That's what you said already in your answer but it's not a proof. (I don't know how to prove it either.)